# How to change directory to desktop on german ubuntu?

Tags: cd-command

I fail to change to the desktop via command line. I tried it like this.

```
cd ~/Desktop
```

But then I get "*File or Path not found*"

Comment: Amend question to, show what you get if you type `ls -l ~`?

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Now i found a folder called "Schreibtisch" which means "Desktop". After executing `cd ~/Schreibtisch` it worked! :)

Comment: If you like you can do `ln -sT Schreibtisch Desktop`.

Comment: The symlink does not work, if i execute `cd ~/Desktop` then i still get "File or Path not found"

Comment: Sorry, you must be in `~` when you create the symlink. This may be better if you have gnu ln `ln -sTr ~/Schreibtisch ~/Desktop` else `pushd ~; ln -sT Schreibtisch Desktop; popd` if you have bash, or `cd ~; ln -sT Schreibtisch Desktop; cd -`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're running into is a one where the name of the directory can change depending on the user's selected language.

In the general case you should be able to run

```
xdg-user-dir DESKTOP
```

to get the path to the current user's Desktop directory.
e.g.

```
% xdg-user-dir DESKTOP
/home/sweh/Desktop
```

Scripts should take this into account when looking for the Desktop folder (e.g. to install shortcut icons).

(If `xdg-user-dir` isn't found then it's possible the user doesn't *have* a GUI desktop; default to "$HOME/Desktop" in that case).

Spec's for the different user-dirs can be found at https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs/

In your specific case, you found manually (as per your comments) that "Schreibtisch" is the name used for your login.